# Tag synonym: [warmth] to [temperature]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I think that [warmth](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warmth) should redirect to [temperature](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/temperature).

Comment: Who is able to create/modify tags? I'm at a disadvantage here because I'm on the mobile app and I don't know what I'm doing in it but I don't see a way to create them.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a synonym, but I agree we should only use one tag for temperature related questions. Not doing so will allow wild growth of unnecessary tags.